# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List... in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am retrieving data after joining from two tables in ASP.net MVC Entity framework but the properties are unaccessible inside view and when i run the code it give error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6..... 
but this dictionary....System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1. Thanks for your answers..

My Code is:

HomeController:

```
 dbEntities dbquery = new dbEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var id = 1;
            var query = (from x in dbquery.Emp_
                         join y in dbquery.Departments on x.Id equals y.emp_id
                         where x.Id == id
                         select new { x.Id, x.EmployeeName, x.Department, y.emp_id, y.Dept_Id, y.DeptName }).ToList(); 
            return View(query.ToList());

        }
```

In View:

@model IEnumerable

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  { 
   @item.... (Properties are inaccessible)
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of anonymous types are not supported by razor views.

You should create a model you could populate. Add all the properties you need in the model.

Instead of

```
  select new { }
```

you would go

```
  select new MyModel  { }
```

The query would return a

```
    List<MyModel>
```

after these changes.

Then in your view you would change the model to:

```
     @model IEnumerable<MyModel>
```

Comment: hi i do the same way but still have this problem! what should i do?

Comment: @minaa.beigi What type have you in your view (`@model`), and what type does your controller action return?

Comment: @scheien  in my view use `IEnumerable<MyModel>` and my action return a list view but i found a way! select from a table `AsEnumerable()` so i use this code  `var list = (from p in _dbContext.tbl_Tpaper.AsEnumerable()
                        where p.Username == Name
                        select new Teacherpapers { PaperName = p.PaperName, id=p.id }).ToList()`